# lsb_release called every few seconds

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, top

I have an odroid XU4 running the manufacturer-provided minimal Ubuntu 18.04. Every few seconds (it's not really consistent, but think between 5 and 30) I get a call to lsb_release. Sometimes it gets called with the `-r` flag, others with `-i`. This causes a spike in CPU usage that turns on the board's fan (which is quite annoying).

I saw [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/324761/why-is-ubuntu-lsb-release-being-called-every-30-seconds), but disabling auto-updates in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20unattended-upgrades did not reduce the number of calls. Since this is a python script, I tried to track the caller using the methods described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114712/how-to-get-the-caller-script-name). However, the one with `os.getppid` does not work if the caller is not another python script (at least in my testing), and the second one with psutil does not work because `import psutil` fails when done within lsb_release for some reason.

Did anyone encounter this and know where all this calls come from? Or perhaps someone has other ideas to track who is calling lsb_release? Thanks!

Edit: average over 40 minutes is 1 call every 7 seconds. 51.1% of the calls have `-r`, the rest have `-i`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could temporarily move `/usr/bin/lsb-release` to `/usr/bin/orig-lsb-release` and put a script in its place containing something along the lines of

```
#!/bin/sh
ps axf > /tmp/inflagranti.txt
exec /usr/bin/orig-lsb-release "$@"
```

Then when the file `/tmp/inflagranti.txt` has been created you can move `/usr/bin/orig-lsb-release` back to `/usr/bin/lsb-release` and peruse `/tmp/inflagranti.txt` at leisure to find who called your script.

Comment: This would not work because lsb_release is run as `python3 /path/to/script`, but you inspired me to use the `subprocess` module to run `ps axf`. Sure enough, the calls with the `-i` flag seem to come from `cloudshell-lcd`, which is a small program to control an LCD screen. I will have a look there to see why this is being called so much, and then have another look to find the `-r` caller. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It seems I can't upvote, but I marked your answer as accepted. Cheers!

Comment: For future reference, the calls with `-r` are also due to `cloudshell-lcd`